# Unable to paste copied text or url in an HTML form text input area

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have an HTML page designed in Bootstrap 5 which has a simple form with a single text input field. When I test the page in my desktop or laptop, I am able to copy any text or web link and paste it into the form's text input field. If the test the same page from my live website and test it in my mobile phone's browser, the paste operation sometimes works and sometimes does not.

On older Android phones, if I copy some text and then try to paste it into my form, it works. But, if I use a relatively new Android phone, I am unable to paste the copied text. It appears as if the text was not copied properly, i.e. the clipboard is empty.

Is this an issue with my code or JavaScript loaded in my html or is this an issue with my mobile device?

Please advise.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Navbar Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img class="img-fluid ps-5 pt-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Example Logo" width="150" height="50" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0">
        </a>
        <!-- Toggler/Collapsible Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto ms-sm-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-2 align-items-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Headline -->
  <div class="container mt-5 pt-3 pb-1" style="width: 70%;">
    <h3>Example Website</h3>
    <p>Demonstrate HTML5 Forms</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Form Input Area -->
  <div class="container rounded mt-3 pt-3 pb-1 bg-dark text-white" style="width: 70%;">
    <form method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/35" width="35" height="35"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" name="fullname" required>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Compulsory field</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check ms-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="check1" name="checkrules" value="accept" required>
        <label class="form-check-label">I accept the rules <a href="rules.html" target="_blank">policy</a>.</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container mt-5 pt-3 pb-1" style="width: 70%;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="test1">
        <p class="text-center mt-2">Test 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="test2">
        <p class="text-center mt-2">Test 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="test3">
        <p class="text-center mt-2">Test 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Description -->
  <div class="container mt-5 pt-3 pb-1" style="width: 70%;">
    <h5>Welcome to Example.com</h5>
    <ul>
      <li>Sentence 1</li>
      <li>Sentence 2</li>
      <li>Sentence 3</li>
      <li>Sentence 4</li>
      <li>Sentence 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <p class="text-muted text-center">Copyright &copy
        <script>
          document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
        </script> Example</p>
      <p class="text-muted text-center"><a href="rules.html" class="text-secondary">Rules</a></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've converted your markup to a snippet demo. Does it show the problem? Copy/paste is an operating system feature and likely not related to your site.

Comment: Also, you should not be using inline styles. That's difficult way to work. Use Bootstrap classes and custom CSS.

Comment: I was able to copy and paste a link to the snippet form both from a desktop device as well as from an android phone. Surprisingly, I was able to paste the same clipboard contents in my actual live website form as well. The inability to copy and paste occurs randomly on a few android phones. It is never an issue from my desktop. Is it possible that clipboard contents expire if pasted once or when switching multiple times between browser windows?